# PHP remove all occurrences of a string in a string

Tags: php, regex, string, cell

I had a large PDF. I converted it to a table. Since it was a free program, it did a poor job. My cells look like this:

```
 ---------------------------------------
| bb.M2.u4.F5  bb.M2.u4.F5  bb.M2.u4.F5 |
 ---------------------------------------
```

When it should just look like this (note the white-space):

```
 -----------
|bb.M2.u4.F5|
 -----------
```

I want to upload the whole contents of the file to my database. But before I upload, **I must clear the data of re-occurring strings in each string**.

How do I achieve this?

```
$my_string = " bb.M2.u4.F5  bb.M2.u4.F5  bb.M2.u4.F5 ";

$my_string = WhatFunctionCanIUseAndHow($my_string) // Would echo this: bb.M2.u4.F5
```

How?
P.S. the re-occurrence may occur less or more than 4 times. Never know.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need of a regex. Just split on space and take the first element at 0 index. Also, use `trim()` to trim the spaces before exploding.

```
$my_arr = explode(" ", trim($my_string));
echo $my_arr[0]; // bb.M2.u4.F5
```

Comment: @adeneo ok. I got your point. You can't just chain the array. I've edited it to make it more right. /ot are you on windows 8+ and have minions game installed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this lookahead based regex:

```
$my_string = ' bb.M2.u4.F5  bb.M2.u4.F5  bb.M2.u4.F5 ';
$my_string = preg_replace('/ *(\b\w+\b)\.? *(?=.*\b\1\b)/', '', $my_string);
//=> bb.M2.u4.F5
```

This regex captures a group of word characters using `(\b\w+\b)` and then uses a lookahead `(?=.*\b\1\b)` to make sure same word exists in the string.

Replacement is just with an empty string.

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tG9aA5/1)